# Smooth interpolation of my data

Tags: r

I'm trying create smooth lines on a plot which include the maxima of the data points. I've searched around a lot and have tinkered with loess() and ksmooth() but I'm yet to make it work.

My best attempt so far has been with ksmooth() but the line doesn't pass through the maximum data point

[image]

I'm a chemist, not a statistician, so the methods/descriptions of various smoothing techniques often go over my head. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

**Edit:** Just wanted to make a few things clearer. Basically what I'm after is a smoothed version of the following plot with the line passing through the maximum y value.

[image]

To generate the plot in the first picture I used the following code:

```
plot(ChiM~Temp, xlim=c(2,6), ylim=c(0,0.225), lwd=2, pch=16, col='red',subset=(v=='20'), main='Out-of-Phase AC Suscetability Plot', xlab='Temperature (K)', ylab=expression(chi[M]*'" (cm'^3*~'mol'^-1*')'))
setone <- subset(DSM32ac, v=='20') #v=20 is the subset of the data I have provided
attach(setone)
lines(ksmooth(Temp, ChiM, 'normal', bandwidth=0.5), col='red',lwd=2)
```

I hope this makes things a little clearer. If you need any more information to answer this question just let me know.

**Edit 2:** I've removed the data since I can't make a neat table. If it's really important I'll try and put it back in.

Comment: You're right; a smooth interpolation is what I want. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: If `DF` is an input data frame then `dput(DF)` will output it in a reproducible manner so that responders can easily copy and paste it into their session.

Comment: Alright I understand now. If I ever have another question I'll make sure I use dput().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
y <- c(.07, .12, .17, .11, .04, .02, .01)
x <- seq_along(y)

s <- spline(x, y)

plot(y ~ x)
lines(s)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks like what I'm after, so interpolation is what I want. Thanks for your suggestion. I have a few follow up questions if you don't mind. 1. Is there a variable I can change to make the line a bit smoother? 2. I have seven data series that I'm going to be putting on the one graph. For lines() as I used in my second graph I can use subset(), but that doesn't seem to be an option with splines. Is the best bet to make all my subsets first, then apply splines to each?

Comment: You can ignore the last comment. I have it all worked out. For anybody else who comes across this you can make the line less jagged by using the n=x arguement with spline(). Increasing the number used as x increases the smoothness of the curve.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
n <- 10 # generate 10 data points
d <- data.frame(x = 1:n, y = rnorm(n))

# with loes smoothing (span parameter controls the degree of smoothing)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_point(data=d,aes(x,y), size=5) + 
  geom_smooth(data=d,aes(x,y, colour='span=0.5'), span=0.5, se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d,aes(x,y, colour='span=0.6'), span=0.6, se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d,aes(x,y, colour='span=0.7'), span=0.7, se=FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d,aes(x,y, colour='span=0.8'), span=0.8, se=FALSE)
```

[image]

```
# with B-spline curves using lm (degree of polynomial fitted controls the smoothness)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x, y), size=5) +
  geom_smooth(data=d, aes(x, y,col='degree=3'), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 3), se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d, aes(x, y,col='degree=4'), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 4), se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d, aes(x, y,col='degree=5'), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 5), se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d, aes(x, y,col='degree=6'), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 6), se = FALSE) +
  geom_smooth(data=d, aes(x, y,col='degree=7'), method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::bs(x, 6), se = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
# with smooth.spline (spar parameter control smoothness of the fitted curve)
colors <- rainbow(100)
plot(d$x, d$y, pch=19, xlab='x', ylab='y')
i <- 1
for (spar in seq(0.001,1,length=100)) {
  lines(smooth.spline(d$x, d$y, spar=spar, all.knots=TRUE)$y, col=colors[i])
  i <- i + 1
}
points(d$x, d$y, pch=19)
```

[image]